# How do I create a Dart Server database?

Tags: dart, server-side

I know that it is possible to create a IndexedDb at client side, but I was wondering if it possible to create a key/value store server Side. In that case we could use that db as a cache server or even as an elasticSearch server, or maybe replace a SQL or NoSQL database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any database on the server where a Dart driver is available (not so many yet, but in the future there will be support for most mainstream databases.

take a look at

- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/yomp_db
- http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mongo_dart
- http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqljocky

Comment: Not exactly IndexedDB but I think most databases can be used to store key-values pairs. What's the point in having IndexedDB on the server?

Comment: I'm an IDB developer and would be interested to have heard an IDB-related answer. Seems this does not create an IDB Dart server, which is what I was hoping (and I thought was what the question was asking). I'll remove IDB tag.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not possible to create an IndexedDb on the server in Dart. The implementation primarily leverages the APIs provided by the client-side navigator (eg. Chrome, Firefox, etc). IndexedDb is a [developing web standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) which will hopefully be implemented in [all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb) in the future. In this way, Dart is basically using APIs to access a separate database (albeit a very simple one). It is not implemented in Dart itself.

That said, in addition to other serverside database APIs, there is also a Dart client interface for [memcache](https://github.com/rikulo/memcached-client) which can be run on the sever to connect to a [memcache instance](http://memcached.org/)